# Unable to extract item from data object in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, object

I have the following data:

```
var messages = 
[{
  "key": "tFhmw5oQoPhk8nF2sx5rE5BFqxxbjhbajbabjxabs",
  "messageKey":  
      { 
        "-MbY9mE7EFxj78uXrxEc": 
            {
              "senderId": "tFhmw5oQoPhk8naksbjk", 
              "text": "Get at me if you want to sort a place out together", 
              "timestamp": 1623013925991, 
              "user": [Object]
            }
      }, 
  "name": "Oli", 
  "photo":"file:///xfcjgvjhvkvbkjXXXX/CoreSimulator/Devices/CCB652E1-63DB-4E81-B776-DAAB95AFB2AF/data/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0059.JPEG", 
  "receiverUid": "wx4QpIB8n0fYEgTHa6HR86Vassccsc"
}]
```

When I try to extract an item from the data object the console.log shows the item as undefined. For instance console.log(messages.receiverUid) returns undefined. However, console.log(messages) returns the above data object as expected. Do you know what may be causing this?

Comment: what does  `console.log(typeof messages)` show?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It shows object

Answer (score 0):

`console.log` output shows root level objects immediately, but you're not seeing the associated list of properties until you expand the object with the toggle arrow.. it's possible those properties are added after the fact (if even by milliseconds). Try this

```
 messages = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(messages));
```

Comment: console.log(messages.receiverUid) still returns undefined when using the above

Comment: If I try JSON.parse(messages) I get the error JSON Parse error: Unexpected EOF

Comment: Sorry, this is actually  wrapped in the array brackets as above but it's a bit strange that typeof returns object.

Comment: I removed the outer brackets by using var newMessages = JSON.stringify(messages).substring(1, JSON.stringify(messages).length-1); and then used the above JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newMessages)) but the typeof returns string. Any ideas on what I need to do to get it back to an object?